# Node.js symlink junctions are broken on Windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, junction

First, here's the code:

```
const FS = require('fs');
const OS = require('os');
const symlinkType = OS.platform() === 'win32' ? 'junction' : 'file';

FS.symlink(target, path, symlinkType, err => {
    if(err) {
        console.error(`Failed to create ${symlinkType} ${path} -> ${target}`);
    } else {
        console.log(`Created ${symlinkType} ${path} -> ${target}`);
    }
})
```

This spits out a bunch of messages like this:

```
Created junction C:\Users\Mark\*snip*\data\Pacific\Midway.txt -> C:\Users\Mark\*snip*\data\Pacific\Pago_Pago.txt
Created junction C:\Users\Mark\*snip*\data\Pacific\Samoa.txt -> C:\Users\Mark\*snip*\data\Pacific\Pago_Pago.txt
Created junction C:\Users\Mark\*snip*\data\Pacific\Ponape.txt -> C:\Users\Mark\*snip*\data\Pacific\Pohnpei.txt
```

So it looks like it's working. I can see the junctions/shortcuts in Explorer:

[image]

But they're all broken. i.e., double clicking them gives me an error message

> Cuba.txt is not accessible.
>   The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

How come? How can I create symlinks in Node.js on Windows such that the files work like normal (i.e. other programs can read them).

Comment: Hardlinks (`fs.link`) see to work just fine. Windows shows no indication that the file *is* a hardlink, but editing one of the linked files and then looking at another shows that they all point to the same data.

Comment: On Windows, a shortcut is not a symlink so I presume a symlink is not a shortcut (yes, symlinks actually exist on NTFS). Instead of double clicking try cd'ing to it

Comment: @slebetman They're actually files, not directories. Can't `cd` into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I remember NTFS junction points act like directories, not individual files.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: So I should create hardlinks on files, and junctions on dirs?

Comment: Yes, that's the combination that works without extra privs.