# What versions of Angular 2 and Angular-cli worktogether on windows vista?

Tags: node.js, angular

would anybody happen to know the latest versions that work together on Windows Vista?  I've been back and forth trying to get the right combination together but `ng new` never works for some reason or another.

(this is the older post showing what I already tried)

I'm having a bit of a problem here.  I attempted to update `angular/cli` and I got errors telling me I need to update my version of node.  I have windows vista so I'm pretty much stuck with `node 5.7` and `npm 3.6` until I can afford a new computer.

I tried uninstalling angular and clearing the cache and installing `angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.14` and it installs.  I can create a new project with it though it takes a long time to create it, and it also throws an error with `node-pre-gyp`.  I came across an article on Github that said it's meant to be installed locally in the project and not globally.  So I tried uninstalling, clearing cache and installing without `-g` to make it local within my project folder and it still has errors installing and I still can't serve my project.

How can I clear this all up and just start back with a clean slate of Angular2?  I've looked around and everything I find leads me to the docs which are now updated to something beyond what my computer can handle.

Answer (score 0):

> I have windows vista so I'm pretty much stuck with node 5.7 and npm 3.6 until I can afford a new computer.

Have you considered running Linux? There are many versions with a lightweight GUI that runs well on older hardware. [Ubuntu Mate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_(operating_system)#Variants) is an example. It's harder to run node on Windows because of [symlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43036970/node-js-symlink-junctions-are-broken-on-windows).

Comment: only thing about that is I wouldn't be able to install my adobe bundle on Linux and I can't afford the time of the learning curve to work with their graphics software and attempt to convert all my templates and such over.  I'm sure there's some software that allows me to run it in a shell of some sort but I'd just rather not take myself through that when I have projects to do.